# CSV connection to CPLEX with DBConnection

Tags: csv, input, cplex, opl

I want to connect CPLEX with a CSV formatted file where my data is supposed to be written and read.

I think I correctly connected CSV files in the folder "provacsv" like this:

```
DBConnection db("odbc","DRIVER={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; DBQ=C:\\Users\\Giovanni\\opl\\provacsv");
```

However I cannot read data, even as simple as a column of 2 values. I'm using the following syntax:

```
c from DBRead(db,"SELECT c FROM cb.csv");
b from DBRead(db,"SELECT b FROM cb.csv");
A from DBRead(db,"SELECT * FROM A.csv");    // A is a matrix of values (like 2X2 matrix)
```

I would also like to write the output of my file with something like:

```
x to DBWrite(db,"WRITE x TO x.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example from IBM Support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21976826) which basically boils down to using the ODBC driver. with Microsoft Access. Put this code in a `*.dat` file:

```
DBConnection db("odbc","DRIVER={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; DBQ=.\\data");
Gasolines,Gas from DBRead(db,"SELECT name,name,demand,price,octane,lead FROM GasData.csv");
Oils,Oil from DBRead(db,"SELECT name,name,capacity,price,octane,lead FROM OilData.csv");
MaxProduction = 14000;
ProdCost = 4;
```

Then in a subfolder `.\data` you have to put your `*.csv` files. I tried it with the compatible Access driver and it threw errors that the elements are not defined. But at least this is the official way to do it in an official IBM example.

Answer (score -2):

For read csv

You should use IloOplInputFile:

Suppose you have this export.cvs file

```
Nicolas;2;
Alexander;3;
```

Then you could write

```
tuple t
{
string firstname;
int number;
}

{t} s={};

execute
{
var f=new IloOplInputFile("export.csv");
while (!f.eof)
{
var str=f.readline();
//writeln(str);
var ar=str.split(";");
if (ar.length==3) s.add(ar[0],Opl.intValue(ar[1]));
}
f.close();
}

execute
{
writeln(s);
}
```

which will read the csv file and compute the tuple set s:

```
{<"Nicolas" 2> <"Alexander" 3>}
```

and for write

```
tuple t
{
string firstname;
int number;
}

{t} s={<"Nicolas",2>,<"Alexander",3>};

execute
{
var f=new IloOplOutputFile("export.csv");
for(var i in s)
{
f.writeln(i.firstname,";",i.number,";");
}
f.close();
}
```

writes a file export.csv

```
Nicolas;2;
Alexander;3;
```

This can be also read at

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=538340b3-3e1a-4951-bed3-48cac63e7c29&ps=25

and

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=3fd44d41-210b-4b81-a005-819530d6377b&ps=25